# MySQL запрос в консоле работает а через Laravel нет

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Выполняю запрос в консоли MySQL в PhpStorm и все работает:

```
SELECT * FROM users_infos AS ui
      LEFT JOIN users AS u ON (ui.user_id = u.id)
      LEFT JOIN role_user AS ru ON (ru.user_id = u.id)
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM cases GROUP BY `user_id` ORDER BY `order`) AS c ON (c.user_id = ui.user_id)
    WHERE ru.role_id = 3
    LIMIT 100
```

Тот же самый запрос выполняю в Larvel 5.3 и выдает ошибку:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'cutehub.cases.case_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: SELECT * FROM users_infos AS ui
LEFT JOIN users AS u ON (ui.user_id = u.id)
LEFT JOIN role_user AS ru ON (ru.user_id = u.id)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM cases GROUP BY `user_id` ORDER BY `order`) AS c ON (c.user_id = ui.user_id)
WHERE ru.role_id = 3
LIMIT 100)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это реакция на подзапрос

```
SELECT * FROM cases GROUP BY `user_id` ORDER BY `order`
```

Вероятно, для соединения устанавливается сессионная [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by).

Возможные решения:

1. Перенастройка соединения;
2. Установка переменной локально (мультизапросом) для данного запроса;
3. Замена звёздочки на явное перечисление необходимых полей и применение к ним при необходимости агрегатных функций.

Рекомендую последнее.

PS. ORDER BY в подзапросе не имеет смысла. Можно убрать.

PPS. Видимое использование результатов подзапроса - только для связывания. Если так, то достаточно подзапроса

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM cases
```